How to write cumulative density function and expected value in Gekko?
Suppose that X is a uniform random variable within the [\mu-a,\mu+a] range. If a=0, then, X will be a constant. Also, it is possible that the support of X is either positive, or negative or taking both negative and positive. It should be noted that \mu can be either negative or positive. Suppose in our optimization problem, the decision variable is y>= 0. Now, I have an objective function as follows:
P = (c_1 + F_X(y))*(c_2+E(X I{X>=y}))

where c_i are constant and E(X) is the expected value, and I{} is indicator function. I am wondering how I can optimize this problem. Also, F_X(y) is the CDF of random variable X.

There are multiple ways to approach the problem depending on whether there are data points or if this is a strictly theoretical problem.
Theoretical Optimization
For a mathematical problem, it is easy to visualize the objective function as a function of the single adjustable variable y. If y<=mu-a then the CDF function is zero and if y>=mu+a then the CDF function is one. The expected value E(X 1{X>=y}) includes the indicator function 1{X>=y} that is one if X>=y and zero otherwise. This function becomes E(X 1{X>=y}) = 1/(4a) * ((u+a)^2-y^2) within the range 0 to mu. The plot shows that the maximum objective is around y=4.2.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Parameters
mu = 5; a = 2
c_1 = 1.0; c_2 = 2.0

y = np.linspace(0,10,200)
F_X = np.clip(1/(2*a) * (y-(mu-a)),0,1)
E = np.clip((1/(4*a))*((mu+a)**2-y**2),0,mu)

P = (c_1+F_X)*(c_2+E)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(y,P,'k-.',label='P')
plt.grid(); plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Objective')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(y,F_X,'b:',label='F_X (CDF)')
plt.plot(y,E,'r--',label='E (Expected Value X>=y)')
plt.xlabel('y'); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('obj.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()

Gekko can be used to precisely find the maximum of the function.
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
mu = 5; a = 2
c_1 = 1.0; c_2 = 2.0

m = GEKKO()

# variable with bound, y>=0
y = m.Var(mu,lb=0)

# CDF
F_X = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1)
m.Equation(F_X == (1/(2*a))*(y-(mu-a)))

# E(X 1{X>=y})
E = m.Var(lb=0,ub=mu)
m.Equation(E == (1/(4*a))*((mu+a)**2-y**2))

m.Maximize((c_1+F_X)*(c_2+E))
m.solve(disp=False)

print(f'y={y.value[0]}')
print(f'F_X={F_X.value[0]}')
print(f'E={E.value[0]}')

The solution is:
y=4.3333337334
F_X=0.33333343336
E=3.7777774075

Data-Driven Optimization
For data points, use a surrogate function to approximate the CDF. If X is uniformly distributed it approaches a line with enough data:
F_X(y) = 1/(2a) * (y - (mu-a))

However, if the data is not uniformly distributed or there is insufficient data to determine the F_X(y) then the CDF can be empirically determined and approximated with a piece-wise linear (PWL) function such as:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Parameters
mu = 5
a = 2
num_points = 100

# Generate 20 data points for X
# uniform random variable within [mu-a, mu+a]
a = abs(a) # if "a" is negative
np.random.seed(14)
if a == 0:
    X = np.full(num_points, mu)
else:
    X = np.random.uniform(mu-a, mu+a, num_points)

# Sort data points
X_sorted = np.sort(X)

# Generate CDF values
Z_cdf = np.arange(1, num_points + 1) / num_points

# Model
m = GEKKO()
m.options.IMODE = 2

# Piece-wise linear interpolation
x_pwl = m.Param(value=np.linspace(min(X_sorted), max(X_sorted), 100))
z_pwl = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1)
m.pwl(x_pwl, z_pwl, X_sorted, Z_cdf)

m.solve(disp=False)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3.5))
plt.plot(X_sorted, Z_cdf, 'bo', label='Data Points')
plt.plot([mu-a,mu+a], [0,1], 'k:', label='CDF Limit with Large Uniform Data')
plt.plot(x_pwl.value, z_pwl.value, 'r--', label='Piecewise Linear')
plt.xlabel('X'); plt.ylabel('CDF'); plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout(); plt.savefig('pwl.png',dpi=300)
plt.show()

Once there is a functional approximation of the CDF (either linear or PWL), it can be used to optimize the function. The m.if3() gekko function handles conditional statements. However, this conditional function is not needed because the maximum is always within the limit of lower bound mu-a and upper bound mu+a.
